# How to use ₹ symbol in textedit for all values in Winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, symbols

In my form I have 5 textedits to display amounts so I need to add ₹ symbol inform that amounts. how to do this ?

i tried this code but it displaying like this "7,245.00"

```
        decimal total= Convert.ToDecimal(TotalAmount.SummaryText);
        TXE_Total.Text = unittotal.ToString("n2");

        decimal tax = Convert.ToDecimal(TaxAmount.SummaryText);
        TXE_Tax.Text = tax.ToString("n2");

        decimal ship = Convert.ToDecimal(TXE_ShippingAmount.Text);
        TXE_Shipping.Text = ship.ToString("n2");
```

But I need to display like "₹ 7,245.00" this. Help me thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `C2` (for Currency) instead of `n2` to have the currency symbol. You also need to add the culture to your `ToString()` if it's something else by default in your project.

Honestly I don't know which culture have this symbol, but let's say it's japanese *(I know it's not)*, so it would be :

```
    decimal total= Convert.ToDecimal(TotalAmount.SummaryText);
    TXE_Total.Text = unittotal.ToString("C2", new CultureInfo("ja-JP");
```

This returns `¥123.45`

If you need to find the acronym for your culture, you can go [here](http://www.csharp-examples.net/culture-names/).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this :

```
CultureInfo indian = new CultureInfo("hi-IN");
decimal value = 123.99M;
string result = value.ToString("C2", indian);
```

Check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) for more currency format options.